# How to draw a diamond with the path "d" attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, edges

Is anybody able to show me how to draw a diamond using the path "d" attribute? I'm trying to append the diamond to the end of a graph's edge. I haven't been able to find any good examples..I currently have:

```
                var marker = parent.append("marker")
                        .attr("id", id)
                        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
                        .attr("refX", 11)
                        .attr("refY", 5)
                        .attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth")
                        .attr("markerWidth", 7)
                        .attr("markerHeight", 7)
                        .attr("orient", "auto");

                    var path = marker.append("path")
                       // trying to draw a diamond here 
                        .attr("d", "M 0 0 A 200 400 30 1 0 600 200")
                        .style("stroke-width", 1)
                        .style("stroke-dasharray", "1,0")
                        .style("fill", "red")
                        .style("stroke", "black");
```

Comment: Has you some image? to reference what are you trying to achieve. A simple diamond shape, filled or just the path. Could be a jewelry D or card D

Comment: Any sort of diamond shape will do. I saw this example middle of the page but this isn't working for me: http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Paths

Answer (score 3):

Here's a diamond shape. I don't know why you had an elliptical arc in your question as you only really need lines for a diamond.

```js
var path = d3.select("svg")
    .append("path")
    // trying to draw a diamond here 
    .attr("d", "M 50 0 100 100 50 200 0 100 Z")
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "1,0")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("stroke", "black");
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert..that looks great. The problem I'm finding is that in order to keep the shape at the end of the edge I need to start M at 0 0 or somwhere close to that. When I try 50, 0 I lose the shape off the edge, I'm not really sure why. Can I start it at 0,0 and still draw that shape?

Comment: Sure, subtract 50 from all the x values.